# Select an element with suffix id and a class name using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select an element with a id which has suffix as `"_pan1"` and it should has class name  as `oleDiv1` from below code.

```
<div id="44_div_pan1" class="oleDiv1">
<div id="45_div_pan1" class="oleDiv2">
<div id="47_div_pan1" class="oleDiv1">
<div id="48_div_pan2" class="oleDiv4">
```

I can get elements using the suffix form ID name using below code

`$("*[id$='_pan1']")`

but i can not get the combinatined element which has the class `oleDiv1`

This code is not working `$("*[id$='_pan1' .oleDiv1]")`  .

Please help me to correct the mistakes in my above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just combine the selectors without any space between them.

```
$('[id$=_pan].oleDiv1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
console.log($("*[id$='_pan1'].oleDiv1"));
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/yuvitu/1/edit?html,js)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **[attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)**:

```
 $('[id$="_pan1"].oleDiv1')
```